# Por que devemos fazer primeiro um bootloader antes do kernel?

Tags: sistema-operacional, kernel

Por que quando vamos desenvolver um sistema operacional, sempre temos que fazer um *bootloader*, porque não podemos começar pelo *kernel*?

Comment: Porque o bootloader é responsável por inicializar a máquina e carregar o kernel. Mais tarde coloco uma resposta mais completa (horário de trabalho...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode começar por onde quiser. E pode usar um *bootloader* pronto, como muitos fazem. O [GRUB](http://wiki.osdev.org/GRUB) é o mais conhecido.

Como o próprio nome diz ele é o responsável por achar onde está o sistema operacional no disco e colocá-lo na memória, além de fazer algumas configurações na máquina para iniciar a execução de forma adequada. Após esta tarefa ele pode transferir o controle para o *kernel* do OS que já estará na memória.

Em geral o carregador faz uma carga mínima do *kernel* e depois este se encarrega de fazer o resto.

Se quiser se aprofundar, tem um site dedicado à construção de sistemas operacionais. Leia a [página sobre o *bootloader*](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bootloader). Não é algo fácil de fazer, mas é divertido.